# Qt QApplication::commitData, Windows shutdown, confusing documentation

Tags: c++, windows, qt

I'm quite confused as to what should and should not be done in `QApplication::commitData`. The name implies that I should just store the state, and the docs say it should not close the application. However, the default implementation indeed closes all windows thereby closing the application.  Also, if this is not the way to detect windows shutdown, I don't see any other way to tell that windows is indeed being shutdown.

There is also the related `saveState`. The function name means about the same and the documentation is also quite similar.

How am I supposed to properly detect when the system is being shutdown and both save my state and close my application? Is `commitData` indeed the correct way and just suffering from a very poor name and bad documentation?

Answer (score 1):

In my practice to detect an application shutdown I usually connect to the slot `void QCoreApplication::aboutToQuit ()`. As it says in the docu:

> The signal is particularly useful if your application has to do some last-second cleanup. Note that no user interaction is possible in this state.

So far so good this has worked for me properly

Comment: Can't, it is too late in the process. We have a slow shutdown and need to open a progress dialog. Plus, we also have to sometimes cancel the windows shutdown (if we can't safely exit).

Answer (score 0):

commitData() and saveState() may seem redundant.

But the [documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtgui/qguiapplication.html#saveStateRequest)
says

> Futhermore, most session managers will very likely request a saved state immediately after the application has been started. This permits the session manager to learn about the application's restart policy.

Maybe that explains why the notion of 'data' and 'state' are separated.  During that initial call, it would not be user friendly to interact with the user.

The default response to shutdown the application seems like a good design, because if you don't reimplement, then the safest thing to do is to close the app (as if the user had chosen the Quit action), which should also save the user's data.

Is the OS shutting down, or only the session?  As far as your app should be concerned, it is only the session (since technically, the user could be logging off and the OS continues to run.)  And the user might consider the app to be not 'shut down', just 'paused with data safed.'

Also consider mobile platforms like iOS, where an application seeming runs forever.